# how to sync initial files to persistent volume (e.g., NFS)?

Tags: kubernetes, synchronization, persistent-volumes

A webapp (docker image) accesses a directory "/usr/local/myapp" at runtime that has initial files:

```
   /usr/local/myapp/
                    conf/
                        foo.xml
                    web-files/
                        index.html
                        images/
```

In standalone container, the webapp access files under the directory, including reading configuration files, creating new files, deleting files.

For kubernetes cluster, the directory "/usr/local/myapp" needs to be shared in cluster. If using NFS mounting to all pods, all existing files(e.g. conf/foo.xml) under the shared directory will not be accessible (hidden by volume, not sync-ed to volume).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my_web
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: my-web-app:1.0
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/myapp

      volumes:
        - name: my-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-pv-claim
```

For k8s, what is the right way to sync initial existing content from docker image to shared volume(e.g., NFS)? For docker volume, the initial existing content will be sync-ed to the volume if the volume is empty.

Comment: Please read the first sentence in the [tag:kubernetes] tagwiki. Your question is off-topic according to that sentence.

Comment: what is the right tag for this question? Configuration is code. Code running inside POD is docker image?

Comment: The sentence I asked you to read from the tagwiki: *KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. **Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.*** I'm not sure what part of **Configuration and deployment is off-topic here.** isn't clear to you.

Comment: Understand. But If you get a chance to look at questions tagged with kubernetes, there are a lot on configuration.

Comment: Existence of a question does not mean that a new one is on topic. Guidelines mature over time, and new sites are created that didn't exist before. What is relevant are the guidelines in effect at the time you ask your question, and those guidelines say that configuration questions are off-topic now.

Comment: Agree. But a new tag is needed for kubernetes configurations. Most of the questions tagged with kubernetes I came across on SO are about kubernetes configurations.

Comment: No, a new tag isn't needed, because the questions are off-topic here. We don't create tags for off-topic subjects. Once again, guidelines change over time as new sites are created, which is why your question topic is not proper to ask here. This question is most likely suitable for [sf], as it is about configuration of Kubernetes on your server, although I'd suggest you read their help guidelines to make sure before posting. You should look at the available list of [se] sites (you can find a link to it at the bottom of all pages here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when it comes to moving data into mounted folders or volumes, you run an init container that takes care of it. Sadly, there's not really a better way to do this at the moment. When mounting new volumes, if the path exists, every file and folder in it will disappear into thin air. This is true for PVCs as well. However, if the PVC itself already existed and had files, said files won't be deleted upon mounting the volume.

You could also run the startup command on container init, but in order to keep it simple and with only one init command, running it in an init container seems best.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my_web
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - image: my-web-app:1.0
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/myapp
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - cp -R <source-dir> /usr/local/myapp
      containers:
        - image: my-web-app:1.0
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-volume
              mountPath: /usr/local/myapp
      volumes:
        - name: my-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-pv-claim
```

Note: This example only works if these files will not be updated and thus you don't need persistence, thus I would remove the PVC so as to not waste resources. Instead, use a volume of type `emptyDir`.

Also, I don't think NFS in Kubernetes works with PVCs. You can read more about NFS with K8s [here.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs)

Comment: cp -R <source-dir> /usr/local/myapp. The source-dir is the same as the destination dir, and hidden by the mount volume. Also need to check if the volume is empty.

Comment: @eastwater The source directory cannot be the same as the target one, since a Kubernetes volume would empty it. Thus, you should use a different target directory, which would be the same as the volume mount, to copy the files into.